# Teradata Case condition check by ID and Date

Tags: teradata

There are same IDs in multiple records with different startdate and enddate spans.

I need to write a teradata sql case condition to check by ID and whose start date is current month and compare with enddate of previous record

Case condition:
I need to write a teradata sql case condition to check by ID and whose start date is current month and compare with enddate of previous record, if there is a difference greater than 3 months then print 'yes' else 'no'

Just FYI: below activerec field is if the ID has a start date of current month it is shown as yes.

Example the table data is as below:

```
ID   startdate  enddate  name.  activerec 
101 03-01-2023. 11-30-2023 Lee     yes
101 02-01-2023  02-28-2023 Lee     No
101 12-01-2022  12-31-2022 Lee     No
102 03-01-2023  03-31-2023 Mark    yes
102 10-01-2022. 10-31-2022 Mark.   No
```

I need the answer as below:

```
ID   startdate  enddate  name activerec     
101 03-01-2023. 11-30-2023 Lee     yes
101 02-01-2023  02-28-2023 Lee     No
101 12-01-2022  12-31-2022 Lee     No
102 03-01-2023  03-31-2023 Mark    yes
102 10-01-2022. 10-31-2022 Mark.   No

Flag
No
No
No
Yes
No
No
```

Here 101 ID has a startdate as current month and  the enddate of previous record date span is 02-28-2023. I need to compare current month's start date 03-01-2023 with 02-28-2023 to see if it has difference of three months or not. This ID doesn't have a difference of 3 months so I need to print 'No'.

102 ID has a startdate as current month and it's previous record end date 10-31-2022, it has a difference of more than 3 months. So, I need consider this a new member and print as 'Yes'.

I Couldn't do it at all

Comment: Seems much like the prior question. Assuming no overlaps or other strangeness, just get the enddate from the previous record instead of the startdate: `CASE WHEN activerec='yes' and lag(enddate,1,date'1900-01-01') over (partition by ID order by enddate) < add_months(startdate, -3) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as Flag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a translation to SQL:

```
case   -- start date is current month
  when startdate = trunc(current_date, 'mm') 
       -- difference greater than 3 months
   and add_months(lag(enddate) over (partition by id order by startdate), 3)
          < startdate 
  then 'y'
  else 'n' 
end
```